# Can Requiem Masses be said for the souls of the unbaptized?

Tags: catholicism, mass, purgatory, funeral, propitiation

According to Catholic teaching, can Requiem Masses be said for the souls of the deceased unbaptized?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, if they're catechumens:

> [1983 Can. 1183](https://www.vatican.va/archive/cod-iuris-canonici/eng/documents/cic_lib4-cann1166-1190_en.html#CHAPTER_II.) §1. When it concerns funerals, catechumens must be counted among the Christian faithful.

Yes, if they were children whose parents intended to baptize them:

> §2. The local ordinary can permit children whom the parents intended to baptize but who died before baptism to be given ecclesiastical funerals.

> [1983 Can. 1185](https://www.vatican.va/archive/cod-iuris-canonici/eng/documents/cic_lib4-cann1166-1190_en.html#CHAPTER_II.) Any funeral Mass must also be denied a person who is excluded from ecclesiastical funerals.

---

[1917 Code](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7786) can. 1239 more clearly states:

> § 1. Those who die without baptism are not to be accorded ecclesiastical burial.

Yet an exception seems to be given for unbaptized infants; cf. Dom Augustine, [*A Commentary on the New [1917] Code of Canon Law*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=2970), vol. 6, p. 151:

> it is generally admitted that a child not yet born may be buried together with the mother in conse­crated ground.

Comment: The question says "requiem" yet the answer predominately covers funerals and burials. While a funeral is a requiem, not all requiems are funerals, so further evidence would be required to support that no requiem Mass may be offered for the unbaptized beyond a funeral.

Comment: Furthermore, the assertion that the denial of funerals to "heretics" includes the unbaptized needs to be substantiated especially given since it runs roughshod over the distinction between formal and material heresy in general (namely, that the latter is not accorded a moral fault ordinarily) and that heresy is strictly defined in relation to baptism ("Heresy is the obstinate post-baptismal denial of some truth which must be believed with divine and catholic faith, or it is likewise an obstinate doubt concerning the same" CCC 2089)

Answer (score 0):

Strictly excluding funeral Masses, [Canon 901](https://www.vatican.va/archive/cod-iuris-canonici/eng/documents/cic_lib4-cann879-958_en.html#Art._1.) specifies that a priest is free to offer Mass for anyone alive or dead. Therefore we can suppose that he can offer Mass for the deceased unbaptized too.